# Как в верстке сделать такие же шрифты что и в дизайне?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Всем привет.

Есть дизайн сайта, и в исходниках фотошопа в текстах используются шрифты myriad pro regular и sansation light. Как мне можно отобразить их при верстке html странички?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

До чего люди стали ленивые... [тыць](http://pogugli.com/?10752)

Answer (score 0):

Использование шрифтов семейства myriad не совсем законно. Они защищены копирайтом Adobe. Ищите альтернативу.

[Ответ на вопрос](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face)